# wb = xlwings.Workbook() fails on mac

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm just tinkering with xlwings on a mac to write values to cells.  However, when I initialize a new workbook, I get this:

```
import xlwings as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()


Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Developer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Developer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 30, in clean_up
    app('Microsoft Excel').run_VB_macro('CleanUp')
  File "/Developer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 579, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Unknown property, element or command: %r" % name)
AttributeError: Unknown property, element or command: 'run_VB_macro'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Developer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/Developer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 30, in clean_up
    app('Microsoft Excel').run_VB_macro('CleanUp')
  File "/Developer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 579, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Unknown property, element or command: %r" % name)
AttributeError: Unknown property, element or command: 'run_VB_macro'
```

Excel does open and creates a new file, but then the exception happens.  I don't understand why it would be trying to run macros when running on a mac.  I know the author is here. Hopefully, he can weigh in.

Comment: Are you running on xlwings 0.3.0? `xlwings.__version__`

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this error on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, Office 2011 v14.4.6, Python 3.4.2 and xlwings 0.3.0.

Maybe you installed xlwings for Python 2.7? Try the following command as su: `pip3 install xlwings`

Comment: What makes you think he's on Python 3?

Comment: I looked at his question at Code Review and he is starting to code in Python. A beginner will use Python 3 rather than Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I got an error kind of like this, the problem was with the location in which I had installed Anaconda. I uninstalled, and reinstalled it using the default locations given by the installer, and everything worked after that.

Here's the guide to installing/uninstalling Anaconda: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install